# When extending a Javascript Class, can a parent class specify to use a child level class type

Tags: javascript, class, extends

When creating a parent class type, I want to be able to have a number of child types. The parent is constantly remaking itself, and I want the children to be able to remake themselves, instead of being remade as the parent.

Here is an overly simplified example.

```js
class Vector {
   constructor(...c) { this.components = c; }
   add(c) { return new Vector([this.components[0]+c]) }
}
class Vec2 extends Vector {}
```

In this example, If I make a new Vec2, and use its add method, it will return a new Vector, but I want it to return a new Vec2. How is this done in Javascript?

In other words, I want something like this.

```js
class Vector {
   constructor(...c) { this.components = c; }
   add(c) { return new CurrentClassExtension([this.components[0]+c]) }
   //                  ^^^ How to access the Vector or Vec2 or whatever Class extension here
}
class Vec2 extends Vector {}
```

Comment: Why don't you override the add method in the Vec2 class to return a new Vec2?

Comment: Just assume that the parent class has a lot more methods, and overriding all of them would negate the simplicity of just extending the class.

Comment: Does it work, if you use `return new this.constructor(this.components[0]+c)`? Also it looks like you have an extra `]` inside the add function.

Comment: I feel like you're trying to get around the answer by focusing on the over simplified example. Assume that there are lots of child extensions and lots of methods, and trying to recreate all the methods in all the extensions would negate the whole simplicity of the correct answer (if there is one) to this question.

Comment: If *constructing a new instance of the class of the current instance* (`new this.constructor`) isn't what you want, then I have no idea what you want…

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You only would have to do that in the parent class (Vector) not in each extension.